# Spree. No shipping methods available for selected location, please change your address and try again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Getting error(msg) when trying to commit the "Billing address" form. (http ://mystore:3000/checkout/address)

msg ->  `No shipping methods available for selected location, please change your address and try again.`

If I choose in field "Country" as "United States" or "Canada" it works fine, but with other countries It won't commit:)

my Gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'debugger'
gem 'spree', '1.3.2'
gem 'spree_gateway', :github => 'spree/spree_gateway', :branch => '1-3-stable'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', :github => 'spree/spree_auth_devise', :branch => '1-3-stable'
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved :)

Thank you very much NICWN -> https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/spree-user/No$20shipping$20methods$20available$20for$20selected$20location,$20please$20change$20your$20address$20and$20try$20again/spree-user/-imHA2H9KxI/Z_-EKBhq0twJ

1. create new zone "Asia"
2. add country "Japan"
3. in config > states, pick "Japan" and add state "Kanto"
4. And of course, I added a new Shipping Method for Asia zone. 
   {
   name -> Japan (JPY)     {you have to specify the currency in the brackets :) & it has to be the same as in the field "CURRENCY:" & if it's not USD you have to change it in "GENERAL SETTINGS" by choosing currency in "CHOOSE CURRENCY"}
   }
5. Shipping method without choosing any shipping category. "SHIPPING CATEGORY" -->  None.

Answer (score 2):

Another thing that will cause this annoying, ambiguous error, is not having any stock locations set **even if you have `config.track_inventory_levels` set to false**.

Have done more than my fair share of tearing my hair out over this error, since it can be caused by one of 9000 things.

Answer (score 0):

You should check **Zone** in Admin Portal. You can maintain 2 zones. First option can be "USA" + "Canada" , which is spree default as **Domestic shipping**. Another default option is **EU_VAT** for **international shipping**. For any other country which is not a part of **Domestic Shipping** should be member of **International Shipping**. If you are using **FedEx** then you need to get developers key from fedex for **Development Environment** also.

One can find solution for how to obtain developers test keys for **fedex**
http://arvind-ror.blogspot.in/2013/08/how-to-obtain-developers-test-keys-from.html